# A question about the idea of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

In Laplace integral transform equation one multiplies the function $f(t)$ by $e^{-st}$. I read in many tutorials that $e^{-st}$ decays much faster than any other function so the integral diverges.

But what I don't understand what makes one to think to multiply a function with  $e^{-st}$ to transform it in $s$ domain? What is the motivation behind it? Why would you suddenly come up with an idea as such: "Oh there is a function $f(t)$ in time domain what can I do to transform it to complex freq. ($s$) domain? Hmm let me multiply it with $e^{-st}$ and integrate it from zero to infinity" What would have motivated this idea of multiplying and integrating for transformation?

Comment: _"Much faster than any other"_ is a bit of overstatement.

Comment: [This video](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-19-introduction-to-the-laplace-transform/) explains the motivation behind the laplace transform (as far as I remember).

Comment: The motivation was to transform differential equations into algebraic equations. $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} dt = \frac{-e^{-st}}{s} |_{t=0}^{\infty} = \frac1{s}$ , a single variable.  With $\int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st} dt$ typically the term $e^{-st}$ survives the integration and becomes $0$ at $t = \infty$ and $1$ at $t=0$ getting out of the way leaving an algebraic expression to be manipulated.

Answer (score 3):

If we're already used to the idea of relating an infinite sequence $a_n$ to the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n,$ then it might seem natural to relate a function $a(t)$ of the continuous variable $t\in[0,\infty)$ to the infinite integral $\int_{t=0}^\infty a(t)x^tdt.$ However, since we are used to writing exponential functions to the base $e$ with a coefficient in the exponent, and in order to make the integrations less awkward, it's convenient to substitute $x=e^s$ and write $\int_{t=0}^\infty a(t)e^{st}dt.$ This is the familiar Laplace transform of $a(t)$ except that the region of convergence is on the *negative* $s$-axis. Since we are prejudiced in favor of positive numbers, we fix this problem by changing the sign of $s,$ so the Laplace transform of $a(t)$ is defined as $A(s)=\int_{t=0}^\infty a(t)e^{-st}dt.$

Answer (score 1):

Denote by ${\cal R}$ (for response) the space of functions $f:\>{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}\to{\mathbb C}$ that are sufficiently smooth and do not increase faster than some exponential function when $t\to\infty$. Initial value problems of (inhomogeneous) linear  ODEs with constant coefficients typically have their solutions in ${\cal R}$, hence this is an important space in applications.

Consider the innocuously looking functions $$E_s:\> t\mapsto e^{-st}\qquad (s\in{\mathbb C})$$ as **probes** which we use in order to make measurements on individual known or as yet unknown functions $f\in{\cal R}$. The measurement takes the following form: We compute the integral
$$F(s):=\int_0^\infty f(t)\>E_s(t)\>dt=\int_0^\infty f(t)\>e^{-st}\>dt\ .$$
Since $f$ by assumption increases at most exponentially the value $F(s)$ is defined for all complex $s$ with ${\rm Re}\, s>s_0$. This implies that for any $f\in{\cal R}$ its *Laplace transform* $s\mapsto F(s)$  is defined in a full half plane, hence carries enough information to recover $f$ from $F$ (*Lerch's theorem*).

Why should we do this? The central point is that the transform $L:\>f\mapsto F$ has phantastic formal, resp., analytical properties. It transforms a problem involving an unknown function $f$ into a **simpler** problem involving $F$. In particular differentiation in the $t$-world appears as multiplication with $s$ in the $s$-world. Etcetera.